# Authorization failure /services/manage

Tags: cas

I am using Cas overlay approach. From time to time I get problems with getting into /cas/services/manage .

> "
>   Access Denied
>   UsernameNotFoundException::aaa
>   "

Sometimes it actually lets me in. In deployerConfigContext.xml I have declared "aaa" user.

```
<sec:user-service id="userDetailsService">
  <sec:user name="aaa" password="aaa" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
</sec:user-service>
```

What can be causing this inconsistent behaviour?

excerpt from logs showing that authentication went ok

```
2013-07-31 11:53:05,332 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl] -   <org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.SimpleTestUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler successfully authenticated [username: aaa]>
2013-07-31 11:53:05,333 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl] - <Resolved principal aaa>
2013-07-31 11:53:05,333 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl] - <org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.SimpleTestUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler@4b4bc1e authenticated aaa with credential [username: aaa].>
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like user `aaa` is not available in your Authentication Handler. The XML code you supplied just authorizes that user to use that service, it does not allow that user to authentication into CAS.

The inconsistency could be that your Authentication Handler (database/LDAP/in memory to name a few) is not available at the time of authentication.

Comment: An interesting thought. Then it forces another question. Why authentication handler [org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.SimpleTestUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler in my case] is available for other protected page?

Comment: If I am reading logs right https://gist.github.com/Alua-Kinzhebayeva/9f27aa1bc84126577e56 then org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.SimpleTestUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler handles authentication.

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand why user 'qq' wouldn't authenticate with the password of 'qq'. Looking at the SimpleTestUsernamePasswordAuthentic‌​ationHandler, the only way it wouldn't authenticate is that the username and password did not match.

`if (StringUtils.hasText(username) && StringUtils.hasText(password)
            && username.equals(getPasswordEncoder().encode(password))) {
            log
                .debug("User [" + username
                    + "] was successfully authenticated.");
            return true;
        }`

Comment: true, but then we have a config file saying "aaa" is the only admin here.